# how to access a tags with the same classname and handle onClick using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select dropdown with same classname, I will like to return the title when option value is selected. however with the code I have, when a second dropdown is changed, it still returns the value selected in first option dropdown

http://jsfiddle.net/kgrg/ETeZe/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're using to pull out the value:

```
size_title=jQuery('.child_Select_Size  option:selected').attr("title");
```

Is matching all `.child_Select_Size` elements.  To limit to just the one which triggered the event, try:

```
size_title=jQuery('option:selected', this).attr("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because inside the `change` handler `jQuery('.child_Select_Size  option:selected')` will select both the elements `selected` `option` and calling `attr('title')` on these matched elements will always give the `title` of the first element.

You should make use of `this` keyword which points to the `element` which raised the event. `$(this).find` will only look inside the element which raised the event. Also make use `$` instead of `jQuery` if there is no conflict or use `jQuery.noConflict()`

```
$('.child_Select_Size').change(function(elmt){
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr("title"));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ETeZe/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use $(this) to refer to the select box that has changed, instead of just using a new selection (which will grab all).

http://jsfiddle.net/ETeZe/10/

Comment: Also there was some un-needed complexity in your script that I stripped out.